# $A,B,C,B-C$ positive definite, prove the minimum eigenvalue of $BAB$ is greater that of $CAC$.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

$A,B,C,B-C\in R^{n\times n}$ positive definite, prove the minimum eigenvalue of $BAB$ is greater that of $CAC$. At first I try to transform them to canoical forms like diagonal but since congruence transformation chances the order of eigenvalues and of course $B^2-C^2$ is not necessarily positive definite. I have difficulty with this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is true that
$\lambda_\min(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})
=\lambda_\min(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})
>\lambda_\min(A^{1/2}CA^{1/2})
=\lambda_\min(C^{1/2}AC^{1/2})$, your inequality is false in general. Here is a random counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{5&2\\ 2&1},\ B=\pmatrix{4&5\\ 5&22},\ C=\pmatrix{2&0\\ 0&9}.
$$
One can easily verify by Sylvester's criterion that $A,B,C$ and $B-C$ are positive definite, but $\lambda_\min(BAB)=3.2248<3.3168=\lambda_\min(CAC)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it solved my problem

Comment: What if A,C commute each other?

Comment: @Archer This is still false. I haven't a nice counterexample with small integer matrices, but it isn't hard to generate a random counterexample with floating-point matrices.